# Double line break being added instead of one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, core-text

I'm adding a new line into a string as follows:

```
unichar newLineChar = NSNewLineCharacter;
NSString *newLineCharAsStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&newLineChar length:1];
NSString * newLine = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: newLineCharAsStr];
[finalString appendString: newLine];
```

but the result when rendered in Core Text gives me two line breaks. i.e. an empty line in between two chunks of text. I just want to terminate one line and begin the next one on a new line (i.e. without an empty line between).

If I remove the appendString, then the text flows continuously (i.e. no break added) so I can confirm I'm not accidentally adding a line break twice. I've also tried `NSCarriageReturnCharacter`, `NSLineSeparatorCharacter` and `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter` as well as `\r` and `\n`, but this happens in all cases.

I feel like I'm perhaps looking in the wrong place, but can anyone help?

*update*: I gather from one of the links provided below that '\n' in Core Text *ends* a paragraph, inserting a line break below the current line. Which would explain why a line break is always being inserted. So I guess the refined question is, what in Core Text will simply break a line rather than insert a paragraph break? i.e. desired result is

line 1.
line 2.

rather than:

line 1.
line 2.

which is what I'm getting currently.

Comment: what is paraChar in 2nd line?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Now that **is** a more interesting question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define Core Text paragraphs without using newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343787/define-core-text-paragraphs-without-using-newline-character)

Comment: Sorry - mistyped the example. paraChar should be newLineChar. Apologies!

Comment: @beaudrykock:what after replacing that?

Comment: Still didn't work. Problem doesn't lie in this code - lies in Core Text handling of paragraphs. Core Text treats '\n' as a paragraph and automatically inserts a space according to kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing. No way, as far as I can see, to do it otherwise - see my answer below. Thanks for your trouble, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a variant answer on [Define Core Text paragraphs without using newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343787/define-core-text-paragraphs-without-using-newline-character) as trojanfoe suggested. There's simply no way to force Core Text to treat a new line character as just that and not a paragraph break.

Consequently, the only way to shrink the paragraph spacing so that '\n' breaks the line only, is to set 'kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing' and 'kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacingBefore' in the Core Text paragraph attributes to 0.0, which is what I did - all looks great now.

Comment: Conceptually a paragraph is ended by a newline character, while its content lines wrap when their rects reach the paragraph rect edge.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

In line number 3, I have used `newLineChar` instead of your `paraChar`

```
NSMutableString *finalString=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hi all"];

unichar newLineChar = '\n';    
NSString *newLineCharAsStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&newLineChar length:1];
NSString * newLine = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: newLineCharAsStr];
[finalString appendString: newLine];

[finalString appendString:@"bye now"];

 NSLog(@"==>%@",finalString);
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of code to simply do `[finalString appendString:@"\n"];` and how does this help the OP with his (CoreText-related) issue.  His code is already correct.

Comment: I have updated only `newLineChar` instead of `paraChar` in the code, all are just to show full code.

Comment: But how does it solve the problem?  You have just shown an alternative to using `NSNewLineCharacter` and nothing more.

Comment: And you are correct \n will work, but why he wanted to use unichar for newline para etc... so i solved in his way.. :p

Comment: Check his 2nd line he used **paraChar** I guess there should be **newLineChar**

Comment: Agreed; and I think that could be the cause, however your answer doesn't make that obvious.  However until we know what it is, you can only guess.

Comment: If he is storing \n\n in paraChar (as name suggest) and also he has newLineChar with \n. So I guessed just a silly mistake from him...

Comment: Anoop - sorry for the mistype in the example, but I did mean 'newLineChar' instead of 'paraChar'. And while your example works for a trivial example, it doesn't seem to work when used with Core Text.

Comment: trojanfoe - you're absolutely right that it's a lot of work to simply add '\n', but I wanted to use a unichar.